# What is the difference between InputType and ObjectType in NestJS

Tags: graphql, nestjs

`ObjectType` is clearly defined in the doc here: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#object-types.

However `InputType` is used multiple times on this page without being defined: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mapped-types.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Possibly see the graphql.org discussions of [Object types and fields](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields) vs. [Input types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types).

Comment: The `@InputType()` decorator _was_ defined [on an earlier page](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mutations)

Answer (score 0):

as comments says in official nest.js documentation you can find about InputType decorator.
https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mutations.